# Configure dovecot using postfix to send email from any email to any email

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

I am trying to configure smtp server to allow my applications on the server to use this smtp to send email to/from any email address. I have used all the configurations from http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=mail

The error I am getting is

```
Jun 20 21:10:35 onnlyn postfix/master[7249]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 20 21:10:41 onnlyn postfix/smtpd[7255]: connect from onnlyn.com[::1]
Jun 20 21:10:41 onnlyn postfix/smtpd[7255]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from onnlyn.com[::1]: 454 4.7.1 <danial@redmutex.com>: Relay access denied; from=<server@onnlyn.com> to=<danial@redmutex.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<onnlyn.com>
```

or for an address the same as my domain, I will get this error

```
Jun 20 21:20:27 onnlyn postfix/smtpd[7601]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from onnlyn.com[::1]: 550 5.1.1 <danial@onnlyn.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<server@onnlyn.com> to=<danial@onnlyn.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<onnlyn.com>
```

Comment: Try removing all IPV6 lines from /etc/hosts and add 127.0.0.1 to mynetworks in /etc/postfix/main.cf. Or add ::1 to mynetworks.

Comment: did not work. i left the idea of using postfix and dovecot and simply installed sendmail to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I left the idea of using postfix and dovecot and simply installed sendmail to achieve it.